# Attributes Form -> show description-column but write value-column

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, forms

Concerning value Relation Forms:

[image]

I'd like to show the content of a description field in the dropdown menu, but write the content of the value field.
Sure, with the mouse-over effect, it will show me the description, but actually the value behind the dropdown is irrelevant for the people using the Form, so I'd rather not show the value at all.
I have tried quite a lot with interchanging value, key or description but could not come to any solution.

My aim is to show the following in the dropdown menu
[image]

but write the related value from the layer-table

[image]

so dropdown shows "0 - nicht vorhanden" but in the attribute it should just write "0"

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtual fields to accomplish a custom label for the drop-down menu.

Add new virtual field to the layer that you take values from and use this field as a value column in the value relation widget.